# How to add project that has no its own template to solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 I need to add an exsisting project to solution. This project has no *.sln file so I can't use "Add->Exsisting Project...".

I want to add Firefox Extension code to the solution. This code has no proper template to use, so I have to do it somehow other way. What do you advice me to do?

Comment: I you open the project and it has no solution, VS automatically creates a solution file for it.

Comment: But what I currently want to add to solution is some javascript files. Visual Studio requires some "project file" to choose, but I don't have one.

Comment: You can use a project of any type to add js files to, VS won't compile them or so. Or you can add them to a solution directly: right-click solution, 'Add solution folder' then drag any file into it

Answer (score 0):

A project doesn't need a *.sln file. That is a solution file, and you don't add a solution to a solution. What you need is a project file; a *.XXproj file, where XX is the type of project.

If you don't have a project file either, just create a new project in the solution and copy the files into the project.

Comment: But there is no project like "Firefox Extension" to choose in Visual Studio. There is nothing like "Blank App" either

Comment: @Ludwik11: It seems that you can use a web site project: http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/08/20/write-firefox-extensions-in-visual-studio-with-web-site-projects.aspx/